# UITableView Not Showing Up In Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I have created a static `UITableView` in my storyboard, but when I run it in my simulator it does not show up. Is there some sort of setting that I may have turned on to make the it not visible?

Note that this has been created 100% within the storyboard, so there is no code to show.

Comment: @Inafziger No code yet. Usually just shows up when put into Storyboard, but this time, it isn't.

Comment: @Inafziger static table.

Comment: Did you drag a UITableView into a UIViewController or did you drag a UITableViewController?  Also, have you updated to the most recent version of XCode?

Comment: @AdamG Dragged a UITableView into a UIViewController. Yes, I updated to Xcode5.

Comment: @AdamG I guess the UITableView shows up, but the cells I dragged into the Table View do not. I had no separator for the table so I thought it wasn't showing up.

Comment: @Inafziger I guess the UITableView shows up, but the cells I dragged into the Table View do not. I had no separator for the table so I thought it wasn't showing up.

Comment: Did you accidentally set the `row height` of the table view (on the size inspector panel) to 0 or set the `hidden` flag for the rows to YES?

Answer (score 4):

IF you are using a staic table view but have a TableViewControler make sure that

```
/*
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
and most importantly. 
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
*/
```

Are commented out in your tableViewController class.

hope this helps.

Comment: I had the same issue as Eduardo and this is what my problem was

Comment: This did it for me. The first two methods in your answer were uncommented in my UITableViewController by default.

Answer (score 0):

Did you hook up the delegate and data source to the view controller. If the table is not looking to your view controller for delegation you would get a blank table view.

If its ok there may be any minor errors. [This Blog](http://kurrytran.blogspot.in/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-and.html) explains creating a static table view. You can check the steps you followed with this.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally added sections to mine when I was creating it, after I changed it back to 1 I needed to update the following code to return 1 instead of 0 and that fixed it.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1  //updated from 0 to 1
}
```